# How do I know which Ubuntu package to install?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, opengl, package

I am using an application on Linux, Ubuntu that originally was on Windows. I am missing opengl header files that I had access to with the Windows 10 SDK.

I want to install opengl on my Ubuntu machine. I did a search for it under Ubuntu packages [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=opengl&searchon=names&suite=disco&section=all).

How do I know which package to install?

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Or [AskUbuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com)

Comment: [ubuntu opengl dev package](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=ubuntu+opengl+dev+package) or [apt-cache search freegl](https://pastebin.com/MnzihfWr).

Comment: [`auto-apt`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutoApt) can help if you don't know which package contains a file you need. If you don't even know which file is needed, you can use `auto-apt run your_build_command`, but this will search for packages for every file that is being checked, it does not distinguish between mandatory and optional dependencies.

Comment: OpenGL, suggest : `sudo apt install  libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev freeglut3-dev`

Comment: you can use apt-file to see what packages contain the files you want.